# Best Approach for Integrating With Trizetto Facets

Tags: integration, facet

I have an upcoming project that will require integration with Trizetto’s Facets solution. If anyone would happen to have any experience in this area and could help with the following questions it will be sincerely appreciated!

-In general what are the available options? Is there a BizTalk adapter? Do they offer an API, direct against the database, etc.

-If anyone has experience going directly against the database can you please share the challenges you may have experienced? For example was there a lot of business rules or otherwise that needed to be accounted for since the application was being bypassed. Is referential integrity handled by the database or the application?

Ive invested a considerable amount of time searching but information has been hard to come by. I have come across a integration offering that they have called FXI but cant find any specifics. Beyond that some code dumps from the MSDN Biztalk forums were pointing at Trizetto refereces which lead me to start searching in that direction. I see that BizTalk has both accelerators and adapters for HIPAA solutions but not a specific LOB Adapter for Facets.... and that about sums up what i have been able to find.

Answer (score 1):

Facets eXtended Interface or FXI is a TriZetto product as well.  FXI includes numerous extensions to the core facets application. Some of the extension are the THG or TriZetto HIPAA Gateway, Analytic Rules Engine (ARE), TriZetto Report Server (TRS), TriZetto Letter Generator (TLG) CareAdvance Enterprise (CAE) and Clincal CareAdvance (CCA). The THG repository allows you to take inbound HIPAA Complaint X12 EDI File (834) enrollment, (276/277) eligibility, (835) payment, (837P) claims files and map them to the Facets keyword file format. The THG will also interface with Informatica and Cognos so you can map non-standard files from groups, vendors, and exchanges to the Facets keyword file format as well. With FXI you also get access to web-based APIs to providers, members, and business partners. You can interface these applications easily with your existing rules engines, data warehouses, or Informatica/Cognos driven ETL jobs.

FXI is available as a complete suite solution of ad hoc, allowing the entity to purchase just the components they need. FXI also provides your organization with extended core database tables as well, which will house proprietary information that pertains to your organization for plan modeling, service code scripting, and file conversion mapping.

The organization I work for uses Facets Core, FXI Complete providing us with access to CAE, TRS, ARE, TRG, THG, and eFacets/iFacets web-based API suite. I have worked on every version of Facets from Erisco 1.0 to the latest 5.2 release across numerous health insurance organizations. I have found that THG is the fastest solution for mapping both non-facets and HIPAA Complaint X12 EDI data to the Facets Keyword file format for batch consumption.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Edifecs.  They provided EDI integration software which many of their customers use for integration with Facets.  The integration is done using translation to/from Facet keyword format.